# Retrieve first value from cell array of cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

I have a cell array of cell arrays...

```
    data = {1x16}
           {1x16}
           {1x16}
```

and I am trying to retrieve the first value from each of the cells.. However when I do

```
     data{:}(1)
```

I end up with an error saying

```
      Bad cell reference operation.
```

First of all is there a good reason as to why I shouldn't be allowed to do this? And secondly is there a way around this?

Cheers!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `1D` cell array -

```
first_vals = arrayfun(@(n) data{n}(1),1:numel(data))
```

This should work for a general case -

```
first_vals = reshape(arrayfun(@(n) data{n}(1),1:numel(data)),size(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing it using  a simple for loop :

For instance, this would work :

```
data = [{[1:16]}; {[17:32]}; {[33:48]}];
b= []
for i=1:length(data)
b = [b data{i,1}(1)];
end
```